# Time complexity in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to answer these questions for the following code.

a) What is the time complexity of the complex function?

b) Describe how you would optimise the complex function?

c) What is the new time complexity?

```
def complex(songs):
    for song in songs:
        one_hit = True
        for other_song in songs:
            if other_song != song and other_song.artist == song.artist:
                one_hit = False
        if one_hit:
            yield song
```

**My answer**

a) From what I understand, I think the time complexity of the current implementation is **O(N^2)** because we have a nested for loop and the inner loop is also going through N iterations.

b) We have to somehow not go through the whole list again inside the inner loop.
So would this be a valid change to improve the time complexity? By changing the conditions for the for loop.

```
def complex(songs):
    for song in range(0,len(songs)):
        one_hit = True
        for other_song in range(song,len(songs)):
            if other_song != song and other_song.artist == song.artist:
                one_hit = False
        if one_hit:
            yield song
```

c) Would the complexity go down to **O(log N)**?

Is there any other way of making this piece of code more optimized so the time complexity can go down?

Comment: This question is way too broad, and it's also at least two separate questions, and it doesn't show any effort or research at all toward b (or c, but that question is kind of impossible to answer before you do b). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help.

Comment: By the way, you're right about the time complexity, but "we have a nested for loop" isn't enough to prove that. For example, if the inner loop were `for i in range(2):`, it wouldn't be the same complexity, right? Or if the body of that loop were a recursive call to `complex`? It's only `O(N^2)` if both loop are of length `N`, and the work done in the inner loop is constant time; that's what you need to establish to answer a).

Comment: Make sure you have a thorough understanding of how the code works. If you struggle, create a small example (e.g. A list of 10 songs with artists and names) and try to "execute" the code by hand. If you do this, you should get an idea where the code above is a bit inefficient and you might get a feeling how it can be improved. If you then struggle to write the actual code, identify the problem and reword your question please

Comment: What you have in b) is an optimization, but it's not a huge one. How long is the inner loop when N is 0? When N is 1? When it's len(songs)/2? When it's len(songs)-1? Average them all. Is the answer a small constant times 1, or, log N, or sqrt N, or N, or something else? And meanwhile, how many steps are in your outer loop? The only way you could have log N total time is if one loop were O(1) and the other were O(log N).

Comment: For many problems, the right way to optimize things is to change the data structure. You can't search a list any faster than O(N), because you have to look at every element. But do you know another data structure that you can search in O(log N), or even O(1)? If so, do you know how to copy a list into that data structure fast enough that it doesn't waste more time as you saved?

Comment: Is this one way of doing it? Converting the songs list into a binary search tree problem. We know that binary search takes O(log N) time. So if we can sort the artist into a binary tree in terms of alphabetical artist names. Then we will be able to search the tree faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a defaultdict to parse the input (or as an improvement the specialized collections.Counter class) to reduce the complexity 2*n or O(n):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def less_complex(songs):
     artists = defaultdict(list)
     for song in songs:
          artists[song].append(song)
     for artist, songs in artists.iteritems():
          if len(songs) == 1:
              yield song
```

It takes n to convert the songs to a defaultdict structure but then a constant time to do the lookup. As you don’t care about the order of artists that are yielded this is the most efficient method to my knowledge.

The complexity will never go down to O(log n) because you have to iterate over the complete list of songs at least once to know which one is not there twice.